# Returning a new object by dereferencing a local pointer to it in c++?

Tags: c++, return-value, destructor

I am looking at c++ code that does this, and wondering if it leaks memory, invokes UB but just happens to work on this compiler, or is an idiom properly supported by the language that I can expect to work anywhere.

A relevant example for a type whose entire mutable state consists solely of three doubles.

```
// Including an explicit statement of the 'default' constructor
// just to show that these are the only data members.  Locs 
// have no pointers, containers, references, etc that might 
// refer to anything allocated outside of themselves. 
loc::loc() { X = Y = Z = 0.0; }

// change value of a loc to a random point in the mapped space.
void loc::randomize() {X= rng_coord(); Y = rng_coord(); Z= rng_coord();}

// return a new loc object set to a random point.
loc loc::randomloc() {
   loc *ret = new loc(); 
   ret->randomize(); 
   return (*ret);    // <<==  returns the new object? Or UB?
}
```

The question is about whether the object it's returning still exists when the function returns.  If it's stack-allocated (local) it disappears.  And the type is simple enough that it could be confidently allocated on the stack if the compiler isn't required to detect and make a dynamic allocation for the above kind of return.

When I return a **pointer to** a 'new' object I know that the compiler must detect that and allocate it on the heap so it survives the function return.

But is the compiler also required to allocate on the heap when I'm just **dereferencing** the pointer, and the **value of the pointer** goes out of scope?

IOW, can I dereference a pointer to the object to pass the object itself back, and be sure the compiler won't deallocate it the instant the function exits?

g++ appears to do what I want, but I don't know if it's leaking memory and don't want to rely on something that may just be a compiler quirk.

Comment: I see one `new` and zero `delete`, meaning there are leaks.

Comment: `If it's stack-allocated (local) it disappears` This sounds like a misunderstanding. It is perfectly legit to return a local object *by value*. However, returning a pointer or reference to it invites UB. Same as `int f() { int n = 42; return n; }` is valid, while `int *f() { int n = 42; return &n; }` is not.

Comment: In general, you appear to have the Java approach to object creation: that `new` is somehow necessary. It isn't. Avoid pointers. Just make a local variable of type `loc`. It's a very common mistake for programmers coming from Java, C#, or other "every object lives on the heap" languages.

Answer (score 1):

> if it leaks memory

Yes, it does (assuming the compiler allocates, see below).

> invokes UB

Not on its own.

> or is an idiom properly supported by the language that I can expect to work anywhere.

It is not an idiom, but it will "work" anywhere.

> The question is about whether the object it's returning still exists when the function returns.

It isn't returning the object behind `ret`, but a new one (using the copy constructor). That is why the one behind `ret` gets forgotten, and why there is no UB.

> But is the compiler also required to allocate on the heap when I'm just dereferencing the pointer, and the value of the pointer goes out of scope?

The compiler is free to skip allocations if the result is the same, and it is something they will likely do in this case when you enable optimizations.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot be 100% sure, cause the `new` operator can be user-defined/overloaded, but in general, if you allocate memory with `new`, the only way to get rid of that memory is to `delete` it. Meaning for this particular example, unless a `delete` operator is called on the pointer, the memory is allocated. There is a memory leak here because you don't keep the pointer and you are returning the copy of it -> no way to get the pointer back. If the function returned `Type&`, it still could have been possible to fetch the pointer from the object. But in this case, it's impossible.

There are some functions (OS-specific) to allocate memory on the -heap- stack. But I'm not too much into them and cannot give more info.

### Edit

There is something called **Smart pointer** (if you are not familiar with them) which is responsible for memory management. Please check them out if haven't done yet. They are very important and not only for C++

### Edit 2

Don't confuse stack and heap-allocated objects. Consider a statement

```
{
    void *p = new int();
}
```

Here I have actually 2 objects, one is `p` and the other one is the object, which is pointed out by `p`. When the program goes out of the scope, `p` gets removed, because it's a stack object. But the object pointed by `p` remains because it is a heap-allocated object and needs the `delete` operator to be called on its pointer to be removed. If you keep its pointer somehow (not only through `p`), then you can easily `delete` that object.

```
int& foo()
{
    int* p = new int();
    return *p;
}
// somewhere
int& heapObject = foo();
delete &heapObject; // magic happens
```

Comment: Okay.  Need to keep the VALUE of the pointer around so that delete can eventually be called.  Foo.  That makes sense; I had been thinking about the idiom of using the value as a local in functions calling the constructor and having it deleted when the caller goes out of scope, but that's not part of their contract.

Comment: Yes, and this is the main purpose for the destructors. They are mainly deleting the objects allocated on the heap and kept by the class instance through a pointer.

Comment: Wait...  I just remembered the address-of operator from C.  if I get an object back, can't I pass it directly to delete() using its own address?  The caller who called 'foo = randomloc' would need to call 'delete(&foo)' when done with it.

Comment: If you have copied the object (by returning it for example) then the address-of operator will return the address of the copy, which is not what you want, you need the original address that was returned by new.

Comment: @Zrebbesh this is why I have put *you are copying*. If the return type was `Type&`, then you could. As for now, you are copying your return object.

Comment: Looking at the original code I have to wonder why `new` is being used at all. What's wrong with `loc loc::randomloc() { loc ret; ret.randomize(); return ret; }` That seems to avoid all the problems.

Comment: I had not even considered that possibility.  That looks like you are directly returning a stack-allocated object that goes out of scope when the function returns.  This is the sort of thing that gives me hives as an old C programmer.

Comment: @Zrebbesh You are returning a **copy**. That's perfectly OK (and would also be perfectly OK in C). The original is destroyed but that doesn't mean the copy is. The version that is not OK is `loc* loc::randomloc() { loc ret; ret.randomize(); return &ret; }` but that precisely because that version does not copy the original object.

Comment: It's the implicit copying of return values, isn't it.  Long programming in C has trained me NEVER to expect implicity copying of any kind of dynamically allocated anything.  (and of course doing everything with pointers).  But C++ function return semantics include implicit copying even of complex objects, and that's ... something to get used to.  You're absolutely right that the utility I wanted - in scope for as long as the caller is in scope - is better served by your construction and implicit copying.

Comment: And (just to be complete) `loc& loc::randomloc() { loc ret; ret.randomize(); return ret; }` is not OK as well, as it also does not copy, and a reference to a destroyed object is returned.

Comment: C copies simple struct's in a similar way to C++. So a struct consisting of three doubles would be copied in C in exactly the same way as it would be in C++ (assuming the C++ code didn't include an explicit copy constructor that did something weird).

Comment: @ardserver, I'm aware of smart pointers - and, good point, this is the kind of thing they're for.  But I'm not really used to using them yet. I've implemented garbage collectors for lisp runtimes etc and remember the contortions needed, so I don't really trust their performance.

Comment: @Zrebbesh glad to hear that. Hopefully, now my answer covers your question completely.

Comment: @Zrebbesh The standard smart pointers are nowhere near garbage collection. A `unique_ptr` is a thin wrapper around a raw pointer; a `shared_ptr` is a reference-counted pointer. Both just destroy the managed object when it has no owner.

Comment: your last snippet is not wrong, but it shouldn't pass a code review. Imho what is missing in the answer is a disclaimer that returning a reference isn't the proper solution. If the function wants to return an owning pointer it should return a smart pointer.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I wouldn't agree with you. You can avoid returning smart pointer and instead better maintain the lifecycle of your object. Even if you ban any smart pointer in your program, it's still possible to have a clean code without mem leaks. It all depends on you.

Comment: @arsdever it is not even clear why `new` is used at all here. Just return a copy. It seems like this is what OP actually wants

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 he's not asking what to do. He's asking is it a mem leak or not. If the question was `How to fix this` or `How to make it better`, then obviously, I would suggest either smart ptr or return just the copy or something else. As for this question I gave the info I found necessary to know

Comment: You are answering the question *and* suggest to return a reference. That is not good advice. Nevermind, I told you what I think could be improved on the answer, you disagree, we don't need to discuss it

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 My "suggestion" is not a suggestion at all. He asks if the object gets deleted when going out of the scope, I say if there was a reference, you could fetch the pointer from it. Please read the answer carefully.

Comment: when you post code in an answer ppl will copy and use it. You are not explicitly suggesting it as a good solution, but you also spend not a single word on why it is not a good solution

Comment: That is a mistake of people that copy and paste the stuff, not the mistake of me to answer the question and not the mistake of the person asking the question. I will no longer continue this discussion.

Comment: For what it's worth, both answers were valuable.  The suggestion above by john does what I want for this fn and is a very simple way to correct it (randomloc should just treat the local loc as a value) but more generally I wanted to know whether this is a bogus kind of return and needs to be corrected elsewhere in this code and avoided in the future.  Which is exactly the question arsdever answered: what gets returned when dereferencing is a copy of the object's value, and calling delete() on the copy will leak the allocated object.  This idiom, used a dozen places in this object, is bogus.

Comment: g++ appears to do what I want because it optimizes the allocation away and puts the 'new' loc on the stack where it's annihilated (but its value "returned" on the stack) when the function exits.  So it doesn't leak, but that's only a compiler quirk.  Obviously (in hindsight) allocating it on the stack intentionally as a local is the correct way to get that behavior.